# Calling PHP file from Javascript using HTMLrequest is not working on xampp localserver

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to run a php file from the `Javascript`. I am using a XAMPP server and saved all the files in `htdocs` folder. PHP file is saved in the htdocs folder too and is working fine with the following address `http://localhost/php_test.php` in the chrome

The HTML code being used is written below.

```
<html>
<body></body>
<script>
getOutput();
function getOutput() {
getRequest(
  "php_test.php", // URL for the PHP file
   drawOutput,  // handle successful request
   drawError    // handle error
);
return false;
}  
// handles drawing an error message
function drawError() {
}
// handles the response, adds the html
function drawOutput(responseText) {
}
// helper function for cross-browser request object
function getRequest(url, success, error) {
var req = false;
try{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // IE
    try{
        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
        // try an older version
        try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
if (!req) return false;
if (typeof success != 'function') success = function () {};
if (typeof error!= 'function') error = function () {};
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req.readyState == 4) {
        return req.status === 200 ? 
            success(req.responseText) : error(req.status);
    }
}
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.send(null);
return req;
}
</script>
</html>
```

The PHP file is

```
<?php
     echo 'hello world!';
?>
```

However running the html file shows no output in the Browser. I have tried to debug the code and checked it in the inspect element but cannot see any problem or error.

Comment: Try changing `php_test.php` to `http://localhost/php_test.php`

Comment: `function drawOutput(responseText) {
}`

This function does not do nothing inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions `drawError` and `drawOutput` are empty, how do you suppose them to print anything?

```
function drawError() {

}

function drawOutput(responseText) {

}
```

Try like this:

```
function drawError(error) {
     document.write(error);
}

function drawOutput(responseText) {
     document.write(responseText);
}
```